# Why bumble bee cannot fly aerodynamically?

Tags: aerodynamics, biology

I just saw this pic

[image]

So I got curious and logged in on physics.stack first time, is it true? I am a math major and usually wander on mathstack but I would like to understand why Bumble bee cannot fly according to physics laws but still do? I am only familiar with high school physics, no aerodynamics at all. If some one can explain it to me in easy terms, I'll be obliged.

Comment: The quote isn't being serious, of course the bumblebee does not violate the laws of aerodynamics.

Comment: Note that Wikipedia has a whole section devoted to this misconception: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumblebee#Misconception_about_flight

Comment: I just read a paper which argues quite convincingly that flapping fixed wings won't allow a bumblebee to fly, but then it goes on to explain why moving flexible wings in a circular motion (which is what these insects do) works just fine. So it's quite clear where the misunderstanding is: the shape of the bumblebee wing at rest is not nearly the same as that of the dynamically loaded wing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7839/2451

Comment: And note that no discussion of the subject is complete without xkcd https://xkcd.com/1186/

Answer (score 5):

This is not true. The rumor comes from a paper written in the 30s. The scientist, Antoine Magnan, who made the paper did his calculations wrong and retracted the paper, but, of course, the media wouldn't listen.

Answer (score 5):

If bumblebees were propelled the way fixed-wing aircraft are propelled, their wings would not be aerodynamic.  An airplane needs two devices to become and remain airborne.  Its engines generate thrust, and its wings provide lift.

A bumblebee, however combines both thrust and lift into one integrated device.  The bumblebee's wings, unlike a fixed wing aircraft, and unlike even a helicopter's blades, operate independently of each other.  They oscillate, rather than rotate, and create a powerful vortex above them that generates considerably more lift than a fixed-wing aircraft, and their independent wings create more maneuverability than a helicopter's fixed blades.

An Oxford University team put bumblebees in a wind tunnel and studied the effect produced by the bumblebee's wings: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2009/05/090507194511.htm.  Here is an abstract of the actual study: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00348-009-0631-8.

Although a bumblebee is an inefficient flyer, it's large thorax and nectar-fueled energy consumption overcome the small size of its wings.