# What Continued Upwards Momentum Has to Do with Vortex in Bee Wings?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, aerodynamics, biophysics, vortex

In [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/23603/340807) to [how bumblebees fly](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7839/), it says that

> The wing motion has a sort of double lift feature. By twisting her wings over at the end of each down stroke, the upward momentum is never lost. Basically, this means that even when the wings are going upwards, the wings provide upward lift.

That answer was building off [this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/7860/3408070), which says that a figure-eight motion of the wings is responsible for creating a vortex that gives lift. But I'm confused about the part

> By twisting her wings over at the end of each down stroke, **the upward momentum is never lost**

How does the keeping of the upwards momentum have to do with the vortex? Or does it?